# Date_format - php

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

When I try to format the date of a datetime field in my mysql db, and echos' the result, like this:

```
echo $result["date"];
```

but yet it says for example, 2012-01-03 10:27:53
my script looks like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %b, &Y')
```

and it should then say 01, 03, 2012 (or something like this)
is it wrong "type" of echo code i use, i am new to the whole date_format thing so i dont really know if im doing it right.
whole query:

```
SELECT id, subject, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %b, %Y') FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Please show all your code. That's a MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` function call so we would need to see it in context of your query. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %b, &Y') AS date FROM yourtable`

Comment: do you have `as date` after `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %b, &Y')` ?

Comment: This does not appear to be your original code, as you wouldn't have gotten any output with `echo $result['date'];`, because you never selected the `date` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're selecting the original `date` column value, not the value from `DATE_FORMAT()`.

You need to alias that value like this in your SQL query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %b, &Y') as formatted_date
```

And then pick it up in PHP with:

```
echo $row['formatted_date'];
```